# How to convert lmdb file to PySpark Image DataFrame?

Tags: python, pyspark, python-imaging-library, databricks, lmdb

I have a lmdb file whose value contains jpeg image data in binary string format. I want to save all the images to a folder and create a PySpark DataFrame to do my analysis. I am doing this because I want to train a Mask RCNN model on TensorFlow using this data.

I have two questions:

- Is it a good idea? (I am considering it because this way I will be able to do distributed training and inference.)
- How do I do it?

One way I can go about achieving this: Save images one by one to a folder and then read that folder as a PySpark Image DataFrame.

```py
import io
from PIL import Image

for key, value in lmdb_data:
    with io.BytesIO(value ) as f:
        image = Image.open(f)
        # The image is of class JpegImageFile 
        image.load()
        image.save(f"/tmp/lmdb_images/{key}.{image.format.lower()}")

df = spark.read.format("image").load("/tmp/lmdb_images/")
df.display()
```

Is there any other, more efficient/elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only comment on the **PIL** side of things because I don't use **PySpark**.

If your lmbd data is already a JPEG-encoded image, there is no point decoding it into a `PIL Image` and then re-encoding it back to JPEG to save it to disk. You might as well just write the JPEG you already have to disk. Untested, but it will look something like:

```
for key, value in lmdb_data:
    with open(f"/tmp/...", "wb") as f:
       f.write(value)
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to convert lmdb data to image files? It's taking too much time. Took 11 hours to extract ~400k images. Could you please share some insights on how to think about these decisions.

Comment: Sorry, I am not the person to ask that and it is somewhat different from your original question now that you mention there are 400,000 images. I guess you could use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to map the list of images to threads, but that would maybe require your disk subsystem to be pretty performant. I think you might be better asking a new question and mentioning the number of images and your concerns.